# Airflow Scheduler

Tags: ubuntu, airflow

Hi I'm currently trying to set up the simplest version of Airflow with SequentialExecutor on ubuntu 16.04 on an EC2 cluster.

I've created a dag to run every 5 minutes, but the dag runs gets stuck in queue unless I ssh into the server, run `airflow scheduler`  and leave that terminal window open.

Is there a way to not have to leave the window open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the scheduler as a daemon by passing it the `--daemon` flag. It will run as a background process so it remains active even after you've closed your window. The same flag can be used on the worker and webserver.

```
-D, --daemon          Daemonize instead of running in the foreground
```

Alternatively, you can also run airflow as a service with [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). Airflow has some example [config files](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/1.9.0/scripts/systemd) that you can reference.

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel said, you will need to daemonize the scheduler so that it keeps running in the background. You can have a look at the [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/configuration.html#integration-with-systemd) with systemd / upstart.